# Bad Quality with Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon function

Tags: c#, resources, icons

I try to fetch the icon from an exe, where I have used the below snippet

```
 C#
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(icoFileNam, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
 Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exefilePath);
 ico.Save(fs);
```

The image saved lacks quality. I have saved the image as .ico file.

Can anyone knows how to retain the original quality of the icon present in the exefile?

Answer (score 2):

In the most common cases you can use the extracted icon bitmap data via the [Icon.ToBitmap()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=icon.tobitmap&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap.aspx&ei=GResTr2aLan74QTD5LjmDg&usg=AFQjCNEEyL67Ub1pII6XZ3an3VAJ6xAPpw) method. You can save this image to different formats. However it is  pretty hard to save the icon as  ["true" .ico file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx).

The problem is that there are no embedded encoders for icon images in .Net. So by default the result have been saved as low-color image. If this is unacceptable, the MS is recommended to save raw bitmap data as .ico manually. I suggest you use the [IconLib library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx) that already implement this task:

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe");
MultiIcon mIcon = new MultiIcon();
SingleIcon sIcon = mIcon.Add("notepad");
sIcon.CreateFrom(icon.ToBitmap(), IconOutputFormat.Vista);
sIcon.Save(@"c:\notepad.ico");
```