# .NET - Save icon with high(er) quality

Tags: c#, .net, icons

I am extracting the icon of an external application using `ExtractIconEx`, but when I attempt to save the icon using the `Save()` method of the `Icon` object, the icon is saved with a low quality, as in, the icon seems to have a lower colour depth than desired.

The icon stored inside the application is certainly of a higher quality, as when I save the icon using `ico.ToBitmap().Save("C:\\out.bmp")`, the bitmap that is saved is of full quality/colour depth.

So, how can I save an icon that is of the correct quality?

Comment: Nope, **he's** trying to save a bitmap as an icon, whereas **I** have the icon, and wish to save it correctly.

Comment: The problem is that there are no embedded encoders for icon images in .Net. So by default the result have been saved as low-color image. 
See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925597/bad-quality-with-icon-extractassociatedicon-function/7940458#7940458.