# Write icon to disk in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file-io, icons

I have an icon. Is there a way to save it somewhere on the disk?

I am dealing with a function:

```
Private Function ReturnIcon(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Index As Integer, Optional ByVal small As Boolean = False) As Icon
```

Is there a way to save this to an [ICO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) file (file extension `.ico`)?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you even tried searching with Google, or on SO?

[`Icon.Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.save.aspx)

**Edit 1**: Disregard this. I noticed you wish to save it as an ico.

**Edit 2**: If you wish to preserve the icon format, then you're going to end up with a low quality output (See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844344/net-save-icon-with-higher-quality#comment14123045_10844344)).

I you are extracting the icon from an executable file, I recommend using something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27373/File-Resource-Management-Library-NET) to extract and save the icon resource.

Comment: Downvoting is a great way to let me know which areas of my answer need improvement and that the other answers addressed the problem better than I did. Oh wait...

Comment: I'll get you back to zero. [We're all trying to share the love this summer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/?cb=1). I didn't downvote but I'm guessing its more the tone...